# How to separate classes into custom folders

Tags: salesforcedx, class, folder

I'm new to salesforce and I am really intrigued by the folder "structure" of the system. Hundreds of classes are stored just in /src/classes/.

I tried sfdx with vs code, but just in my new trailhead sandbox and it worked kinda okay (until I tried to edit and save files in dev console - it just coppied the file to /src/classes/ again).

We use IntelliJ with IlluminatedCloud2 and no scratch org, no sfdx.

I'd like to force a change in this and slowly create usable organized structure. Do you have experience in doing so? What would you suggest to try on a sandbox?

Comment: SFDX folder structure is just sugar added. In SF there are no folders for your code, everything is one big happy family. So, as long as you use the SFDX tools you get - imaginary- folders, but they are not really there.

Comment: So the main task is to reorganize files on git and deploy to server however we want. And btw, do you use vs code or illuminatedCloud or it doesn't matter?